# Is it possible to open links into installed PWA on Chrome in macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929198/open-installed-pwa-from-external-url) question but the context is on mobile. Does it defer in any way from the desktop?

I am interested in opening links inside of the PWA on a macbook on Chrome.

Currently when I visit a link, under the scope of a PWA, it opens in the browser even though I have the PWA installed.

Is this a limitation of PWAs on macOS that I am not aware of?

Comment: Looks like they are considering implementing "Link capturing" -> https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/desktop#whats_next