# How open Windows PWA standalone app when user click link?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, chromium

The scenario looks like this.

- User installs our PWA app on windows desktop https://test.app.com
- He gets a notification from the system and clicks on the link in outlook 
   https://test.app.com/test/123.

I expect the link to be loaded in PWA while it opens the browser. Is it possible to use intent filters like in android?

Comment: The user needs to explicitly click on the install button while on their Android device. Are you wishing to not have this step? If so, I don't think you can.

Comment: I think the usage scenario is on a desktop machine (not android) and the user already added the PWA via the "A2HS" link. The reference to Android is for give an example.

Comment: Same question on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929198/open-installed-pwa-from-external-url