# How To open PWA from a link on iOS

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

Seems like this should be simple, and on Android, it appears to be, but on iOS, I cannot figure out how (if?) it's possible to launch my installed PWA from a hyperlink in either a webpage or text messages, etc.

On Android, I just create a link tag that opens a new tab/window and use a url that maps to the address and scope of my PWA's manifest.json:

```
<a href="https://my.pwasite.com/" target="_new">Open MY PWA</a>
```

On Android, as long as the link's url is correct and matched my installed PWA, when it opens the new tab/window, it looks for a corresponding matched PWA, and opens the link inside that "app".

On iOS (ver 13.6), the link just opens a new tab in Safari.  I want it to open my PWA.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open installed PWA from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929198/open-installed-pwa-from-external-url)

Comment: also looking for this solution, any suggestions?