# Can you open installed PWA from external url?

Tags: ios, url, progressive-web-apps

We have an installable PWA and are sending users links in emails that link back to the application. Is there any way to force those links to open within the PWA on iOS instead of Safari?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open installed PWA from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929198/open-installed-pwa-from-external-url)