# How can I open my PWA from email verification link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA where I have to perform an email verification. I'm using Laravel as back-end. There's no issue with generating email and verify token when I'm using the PWA from browser. But when I' using it as app (chrome app, initially for dev. test.). I want that the verification link will open my pwa instead of URL browsing. I mean currently when I click on the verify button from mail, it just browse the verification link in a new tab. But I want it to browse from my PWA app which has been installed at chrome.

( [image] )

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929198/open-installed-pwa-from-external-url